# Unable to launch Jupyter notebook from Anaconda Navigator but notebook is opening from command prompt in Win 10 Pro

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have the lat4est version of Anaconda, Python v3.8 installed on my system running on Windows 10 Pro. I have not installed Anaconda in the default drive but set the path for Python, conda to the installed drive. But in spite of doing everything right as it seems, the Jupyter notebook is not opening when launched from the Anaconda Navigator but opens fine when I type the command from the Windows command prompt. None of the applications displayed in the Anaconda Navigator open and remain stuck as seen in the screenshot attached. But these applications do open when executed independently from the Windows Start menu.
Hope you understand the issue and respond to what may be the issue that makes the Navigator work improperly. I have already reinstalled many times but the issue persists.[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the applications not launching, but you can try going to **Environments** in the navigator, then click launch (looks like a play button) and "Open with Jupyter Notebook". This one works for me.

P.s. choose the environment you are looking for. If you did not create any additional envs, choose 'base'.

Comment: I am sorry. I tried but when I click on the Play button apart from the "Open with Jupyter Notebook", everything else launches fine. Bad luck at my end.